# How to load listener class defined in web.xml in Spring Boot Junit

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have Spring Boot 1.2.4 web application.

I have a listener defined in `web.xml`. I am writing Junit for my application; this listener will have logging framework initilizer. But my Junit is not loading this listener class when running Junit.

How to refer `web.xml` listener in Junit class.